# awx superuser creation automatically

Tags: ansible

I want to create awx super user automatically. i am using the command

`awx-manage createsuperuser --username <NAME>`

if i use this command, it prompt for email and 2 times password. is there any way to skip the prompt and do it automatically.

Comment: doesn't have `--password` and `--email` options similar to `--username`?

Comment: yes it has --username and --email options, but not --password.

Answer (score 0):

Whereby [Creating a Tower Admin from the commandline](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/administration/tipsandtricks.html#creating-a-tower-admin-from-the-commandline) doesn't provide much information, the command

```
/etc/tower# awx-manage help createsuperuser
```

reports an option

```
usage: awx-manage createsuperuser [-h] [--username USERNAME] [--noinput]
                                  [--database DATABASE] [--email EMAIL]
                                  [--version] [-v {0,1,2,3}]
                                  [--settings SETTINGS]
                                  [--pythonpath PYTHONPATH] [--traceback]
                                  [--no-color] [--force-color]

Used to create a superuser.

optional arguments:
  --username USERNAME   Specifies the login for the superuser.
  --noinput, --no-input
                        Tells Django to NOT prompt the user for input of any
                        kind. You must use --username with --noinput, along
                        with an option for any other required field.
                        Superusers created with --noinput will not be able to
                        log in until they're given a valid password.
  --database DATABASE   Specifies the database to use. Default is "default".
  --email EMAIL         Specifies the email for the superuser.
```

to skip the prompt.

```
awx-manage --username USERNAME --no-input --email EMAIL
```

At least as of Ansible Tower v3.8 branch, updating or setting the initial password seems to be possible via

```
awx-manage update_password --username='${USERNAME}' --password='${PASSWORD}'
```

Comment: Thanks, but the issue is this will add the user in postgres db without any password means blank password. in that case what will be the password of the new user ?

Comment: @RajnishKumarSoni, in that case it will be necessary to either [Changing the Tower Admin Password](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/administration/tipsandtricks.html#changing-the-tower-admin-password) later or [Use Expect in a Bash script to provide a password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780893/).

Comment: Yes, expect was my last option. but i wanted to check if there could be other options, thanks, i will try using expect.